# 3D Extrapolation in python (basically, scipy.griddata extended to extrapolate)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, qhull

I am using the griddata function in scipy to interpolate 3 and 4 dimensional data. It works like a champ, except that it returns a bunch of NaNs because some of the points I need are outside the range of the input data. Given that N-d data only works with the "linear" mode interpolation anyway, it should be a snap to have griddata do an extrapolation instead of just returning NaN. Has anyone done this or found a workaround? To clarify: I have unstructured data, so I can't use any of the functions that require a regular grid. 
Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Would it help to fill the points outside the range with some constant value? In that case, you could just specify the fill_value

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to extrapolate? sometimes, getting out NaNs and knowing you are going out of range is a much better choice. I have used Univariate splines from scipy, it silently extrapolates and the results can be quite "off"

Comment: My situation is: I measure some values at a few points, and need to then calculate values at a bunch of other points through inter/extrapolation. So a constant value, or NaN really don't help. I know how temperamental the splines can be, so I was thinking linear would be a safe bet. I would like something that works on N-d data though.

Comment: This is actually a bit more nontrivial than it seems in these triangulation-based methods. For each point outside the tesselation, you need to choose *which* simplex you extrapolate from, and also have a fast algorithm to find this simplex. Also, if you want to avoid discontinuities in the extrapolation, some care is needed. After that is sorted out, however, the linear extrapolation is a simple matter.

Comment: I am just going to do a 2nd run as nearest and use that to fill in the gaps. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One possibility to interpolate & extrapolate data with 3, 4 or actually any dimensions is with [scipy.interpolate.Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html)

The `get_data()` function and `plot_3d()` function are attached to the end for convenience.

### Example data

The example data looks like this (fourth dimension, w, is shown with a color). The data is irregularly spaced and not gridded.

[image]

```
x, y, z, w = get_data(N=200)
plot_3d(x, y, z, w)
```

#### Interpolation & extrapolation in 3d

First, let's setup new x and y coordinates. To make this more interesting, let's extrapolate to minus x and minus y direction. This forms the new x and y range of interest.

```py
xs = np.linspace(-10, 20) # some extrapolation to negative numbers
ys = np.linspace(-10, 20) # some extrapolation to negative numbers
xnew, ynew = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
xnew = xnew.flatten()
ynew = ynew.flatten()
```

Interpolation with [scipy.interpolate.Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html). Now,

```py
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
rbf3 = Rbf(x, y, z, function="multiquadric", smooth=5)
znew = rbf3(xnew, ynew)

plot_3d(xnew, ynew, znew)
```

- There can be as many variables/dimensions as you want. The first arguments (`x`,`y`) are treated as coordinates for the nodes. The last argument before the `function` argument are the "values" which are to be interpolated (now: `z`).
- The `function` argument can be used to control *how* to values are interpolated. *This will affect the results so play with it with your data.*.
- The `smooth` parameter can be used to smooth some noise from the data. If `smooth` is zero, the result is interpolating; it will go through all your data points. If it is positive value, the data is smoother. *This will affect the results so play with it with your data.*.
- Below are the results and the extrapolation is of course badly off. This is just to demonstrate that extrapolation is possible. You might want to fine tune `function` and `smooth` for desired results. Usually, data should not be extrapolated "much" (like in this example)

[image]

### Adding fourth dimension

It is also possible to interpolate & extrapolate to the fourth dimension. Here is how:

```
rbf4 = Rbf(x, y, z, w, function="thin_plate", smooth=5)
wnew = rbf4(xnew, ynew, znew)
plot_3d(xnew, ynew, znew, wnew)
```

- I created another `Rbf` instance for the fourth dimension and I used the `znew` calculated with the `rbf3` (interpolation in 3d).
- I changed the `function` to `"thin_plate"` since it seemed visually to perform better *with this dataset*.
- Here is how the results looks like:
  [image]

#### Appendix: `get_data` and `plot_3d`

For testing purposes:

```
import numpy as np

def get_data():
    np.random.seed(100)
    N = 200
    maxval = 20
    x = np.random.random(N) * maxval
    y = np.random.random(N) * maxval
    z = x ** 2 + np.sqrt(y) * y - y ** 3 + np.random.random(N) + 18 * y ** 2 * 2
    w = x ** 2 - np.log(y + (x * y) ** 2)
    return x, y, z, w


def plot_3d(x, y, z, w=None, show=True):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)
    ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=w if not w is None else "b")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure this will work for you and it is not available yet, but in the development version of numpy there is a 'pad' array function...

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/arraypad.py

One of the options is 'linear_ramp' which extrapolates (pads) outward starting at the edge value and linearly increase/decreases to a specified end value.

It is a pure python function so you could just copy it into your path and import (untested by me though)

Comment: looks totally unrelated to me. here are docs, nothing related to interpolation/extrapolation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html